# How to split a file into characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I am making a python function to find the most common letter in a file. However, I am not able to split the file into characters.

Here is my code so far:

```
def common_letter_file(file):
    try:
        handle = open(file)
    except:
        print('Enter a valid file. Make sure the file is in the same directory as your python program')
        quit()
    for line in handle:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            letter_list = [char for char in word]
        print(letter_list)
    counts = dict()
    for letter in letter_list:
        counts[letter] = counts.get(letter, 0) + 1
    biggest_count = None
    common_letter = None
    for letter,count in counts.items():
        if biggest_count is None or count > biggest_count:
            biggest_count = count
            common_letter = letter
    print('The most common letter was',common_letter,'and its count was',biggest_count)
```

The try and except as well as finding the character with the most frequency is working. However, the spliiting of the file into a list is not working
Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split a string into its individual characters like so:

```
>>> my_str = "foo"
>>> list(my_str)
['f', 'o', 'o']
```

---

**Edit:**
In KAVAY's case, this was suffice:

```
list(handle.read().replace("\n", ""))
```

And would've returned every character, in a list, in order in the file.

Comment: I want to split a file into charcaters and not a string

Comment: @KAVAYSHARMA_ITSMEKAV In your case, you could use `list(handle.read().replace("\n", ""))`

Comment: @KAVAYSHARMA_ITSMEKAV accept the answer if it answered your question !

Comment: Yea , it is showing accept the answer in 3 mins

Answer (score 0):

```
line = "Ihavebeenworkingfor9hours"
line.split()

for i in line.split(): # need not to convert it to explicitly
    print(i)           # the better to check the lines
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```